# Chandy/Misra dining philosophers solution

Tags: algorithms, operating-systems, concurrency, synchronization

So based on the Chandy/Misra section in this Wikipedia [article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dining_philosophers_problem#Chandy.2FMisra_solution) we've got 5 philosophers numbered P1-P5.

Based on this quote:

> For every pair of philosophers contending for a resource, create a fork and give it to the philosopher with the lower ID (n for agent Pn). Each fork can either be dirty or clean. Initially, all forks are dirty
>
> When a philosopher with a fork receives a request message, he keeps the fork if it is clean, but gives it up when it is dirty. If he sends the fork over, he cleans the fork before doing so.

So with the knowledge that all forks are initially dirty, regard the following [quote](http://adit.io/posts/2013-05-11-The-Dining-Philosophers-Problem-With-Ron-Swanson.html) and the image underneath it.

> For every pair of Swansons, give the fork to the guy with the smaller id.

My question is if P3 now requests a second fork from his neighbor P4, will P4 give up his single fork beacause it was dirty, even though he just picked it up?

Comment: This question could use some editing to make it more self-contained. I would guess that most people aren't familiar with the Chandy-Misra solution to the dining philosophers problem and I'm confident that pretty much nobody is familiar with the blog post you link. So I had to read two large sections of webpage before I could even figure out what you were asking about.

Comment: I don't know what else I could add. The wikipedia article should be sufficient to understand how the solution works. The second link was essentially there to provide an illustration so that it's clearer.

Comment: The diagrams in the blog post are incorrect. The protocol requires one fork for each pair of philosophers contending for a resource. The blog has the food in the centre of the table, suggesting that every pair of philosophers is in contention for every resource. This means there should be $\tfrac12n(n+1)=10$ forks, not 5.

Comment: You could add a brief description of the Chanda-Misra solution to the question, to make your question self-contained (and link directly to the relevant section of the Wikipedia article). I actually think the blog post is a very bad illustration, as you can see from the comment I posted a moment ago (but before I read your comment).

Comment: I think the position of the food is irrelevant. The resource that they want to access is that they "want to eat" so they need 2 forks to do that, which means they are competing for the forks not the food. In other words the critical section is the forks.

Comment: But in Chandra-Misra, there is supposed to be a fork for each contending pair of philosophers. In the blog, the positioning of the food makes it look like every pair of philosophers is in contention.

Comment: The way I understood it is that every philosopher wants to eat. Thus every philosopher needs to grab 2 forks, one with each hand. This means for example, that phil 2 wants to grab a fork with his left hand but at the same time phil 3 wants to grab a fork with his right hand. They are in competition for the fork in between them. This scenario repeats itself for every philosopher and his neighbor, as each one needs 2 forks which he can only acquire from the neighbors on his left and right. So they are all in competition with the guys directly beside them.

Comment: In standard dining philosophers, it doesn't matter where you think the food is: there are forks between each pair of adjacent philosophers and a philosopher needs both of the two forks next to him in order to eat. Chandra-Misra deals with a more general situation in which there are several dishes of food on the table. For each pair of philosophers who are interested in a particular dish, there is one fork. So, for example, if five philosophers want a single dish, there are ten forks just for that dish, plus other forks for other dishes. A phil. can only eat from a dish if he has all its forks.

Comment: So, to map the standard dining philosophers to Chandra-Misra, we place a dish between each pair of adjacent philosophers and say that philosophers are only interested in the two dishes adjacent to them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. Whenever a philosopher asks for a fork that is dirty, the philosopher who currently has that fork cleans it and gives it to the person who asked for it.

So, in the initial position, 1 has two dirty forks and can eat, 2, 3 and 4 have one dirty fork each and 5 has no forks at all. If 3 requests a fork from 4, 4 cleans it and gives it to him. This leads to the state where 1 has two dirty forks and can eat, 2 has one dirty fork, 3 has one clean fork and one dirty fork and can eat, and 4 and 5 have no fork.

Comment: If 3 has 2 forks doesn't that mean he can eat?

Comment: Also philosopher 5 should have no forks since he has the highest id, meaning philosophers 4 and 1 took the forks around him. I think the scenario after 3 requests a fork from 4 should be as follows: 1 has 2 forks(both dirty), 2 has 1 dirty fork, 3 has 2 forks(one dirty one clean), 4 has none, five has none. This means 2 philosphers, namely 1 and 3, have 2 forks and are thus ready to eat. Am I right?

Comment: Sorry, yes, I've completely messed this up. I'm sorry for taking a somewhat dismissive tone while being wrong myself. I'll rewrite the answer. (In the mean time, take this as a warning against the power of metaphor. To me, the clean/dirty fork thing implied that philosophers, being very civilized, would only eat with clean forks. I'd assumed that everyone starting with a dirty fork led to a starting transient where people have to swap forks for a bit until somebody has two clean ones, but this is not the case.)

Comment: I've now fixed the answer.

Comment: I don't want to make this an extended chat, but in reply to your last comment in the section above where you said "So, for example, if five philosophers want a single dish, there are ten forks just for that dish, plus other forks for other dishes. A phil. can only eat from a dish if he has all its forks." I'd like to point out that a philosopher can only communicate with his neighbors i.e only 2 phils. If he needs 10 forks as you say then what's he supposed to do? Also in reply to what you said about the shared resources being the food, regard this quote:

Comment: "The Chandy-Misra algorithm can be described as follows. Each shared resource between a pair of nodes is represented as a fork that may reside at either node or may be in transit from one node to another. The nodes or processes are designated as philosophers." So the resource they are competing for would be, if this [article](http://www.academia.edu/4144793/A_Modification_to_the_Chandy-Misra_Dining_Philosophers_Algorithm_to_Support_Dynamic_Resource_Conflict_Graphs) is to be believed, the forks not the food, which would make the number of plates irrelevant.

Comment: That description doesn't make sense. The Chandy-Misra paper is quite clear that there is one fork for each pair of philosophers who are contesting a particular resource. A philosopher must hold all the forks associated with a resource before s/he can access that resource. The plates of food are the resource; the forks are the locking mechanism that prevents concurrent access. (And apologies for repeatedly mis-spelling Mani Chandy's surname.)